# Error message "ERROR - no error information available" when opening DB2 connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, db2

I am getting an error message
 [image]

when I attempt to open a connection to DB2 database from my asp.net application.

```
var db2ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB2DataConnString"];
using (DB2Connection conn = new DB2Connection(db2ConnString.ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this error?